# How to block until all file descriptors are ready? Use select()/poll()/epoll()?

Tags: select, file-io, blocking, file-descriptor, epoll

I am in the situation where I would like a C program to block on a set of file descriptors until all files are ready.  This differs from the traditional select(), poll(), and epoll() system calls that only block until any file descriptor is ready.  Is there a standard function that will block until all files are ready?  Or perhaps there are some other clever tricks?

Obviously, I could call select() in a loop until all file descriptors are ready, but I don't want to incur the overheads of context switches, preemptions, migrations, etc..  I'd rather that the select()'ing task just sleep until all files are ready.

Answer (score 1):

It's not thread safe in case there are other threads operating on some of the same file descriptors at the same time (but you probably shouldn't be doing that anyway) but you can try this:

1. Initialize the poll set to all of the file descriptors you're interested in.
2. `poll()` for the current set of file descriptors
3. When `poll()` returns, scan the `revents` and find all of the file descriptors that are ready. Remove them from the poll set.
4. If there are any file descriptors still in the set, go back to step 2.
5. `poll` one last time with the full set of file descriptors to make sure they are all still ready.
6. If some are not ready anymore, go back to step 1.
7. success

It still may involve many `poll()` calls, but at least it doesn't busy-wait. I don't think there exists a more efficient way.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by looping.  I've looked into extending the Linux kernel to do what I want, but it looks like a non-trivial amount of effort since the file-writing threads need to do some work to determine if a thread should be woken up.